# uri_segment() in codeigniter causes fatal error undefined method

Tags: codeigniter, get, uri

My routes structure is :

```
$route['404_override']          = 'home/check_path';
```

And my `home.php` `check_path()` method is :

```
public function check_path() {
        $slug = $this->uri_segment(1); //<- This is line 68
        //check if event exists
        $event_check = $this->event_model->get_event_id_from_slug($slug);
        if($event_check) {
            redirect('events/view/'.$slug);
        }else{
            redirect('home/not_found');
        }
    }
```

But when I write `http://mypage.com/anything-here` is shows error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Home::uri_segment() in /var/www/html/99fest/application/controllers/home.php on line 68
```

Comment: `$slug = $this->uri->segment(2);` check now

Comment: Same error I am getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
$slug = $this->uri_segment(1);
```

With:

```
$slug = $this->uri->segment(1)
```

See this: http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/uri.html